# mongodb requests on aggregation results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to remove documents which are not in my aggregation.

```
var toto = db.collone.aggregate(..........); --> i tested it works
```

it returns: `[{_id : "" , fieldone : ""},......]`

so I tried:

```
db.colltwo.remove({myfield : {$not : {$in : toto.fieldone}}});
```

I also tried on `find()` request before trying `remove()` for test and nothing works

and it doesn't work at all :(

Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Are you looking for `$nin`? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

Comment: It also would need to be an array of `id`s.